# Laravel attach with variable?

Tags: laravel, mailer

I encountered an interesting problem and I would like to ask for your help in this regard.
I want to attach an invoice in the email, but for some reason I can't do it.

code:

```
        Mail::send('emails.nygta', ['number' => $result->getDocumentNumber(), 'link' => 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/pdf/'.$result->getDocumentNumber().'.pdf'], function($m) use ($email) {
            $m->from('support@task.net', 'task.net');
            $m->to($email, $email)->subject(trans('welcome.nygtsubject'));
            $m->attach(base_path('szamlazzhu/pdf/'.$result->getDocumentNumber().'.pdf'), ['as' => 'NYUGTA.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf']);
        });
```

I checked the route and it points to the right place.

if I added a direct path, for example:

```
base_path('szamlazzhu/pdf/INVOICE-2022-10.pdf')
```

Then it sends the message, perfectly.

getDocumentNumber() -> returns good value.

In the direct path, I enter a non-existent index, and it is only created when creating the invoice, so I am trying to attach an existing pdf file.

Sorry, bad english!

Comment: If it works when you hardcode the value of `$result->getDocumentNumber()` then you should double check what returns `$result->getDocumentNumber()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument into `Mail::send` is an anonymous function, in which you bring `$email` into scope, but not `$result`, so within the function `$result` is undefined.

If you have error logs enabled it should have entry in there about this. Change your function to this and it should work.

```
function($m) use ($email, $result)
```